# PCA vs TSNE vs MDS (review cluster)

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, pca, svd, dimensionality-reduction

I have a well know dataset from Movielens of review and i wish cluster the user for movie taste.

I m starting from a dataset like this:

```
idUser iDmovies review
1       2       1
1       10      2
5       5       5
5       10      2
```

initially i created a matrix with user x movies and fill with review values in this way:

```
       movieid
idUser  2    5   10
    1   1    0    2               
    5   0    5    2
```

my matrix is very sparse so i applied a matrix factorization to filler the value and now i have a matrix in this way(just an example):

```
          movieid
    idUser  2    5   10
        1   1    -2    2               
        5   -2    5    2
```

Know have sense to apply on this dataset the PCA o TSNE or Kmeans? or is preferible apply MDS?

I tried to apply PCA on this dataset and i had this:

[image]

and I think is really bad.
After that i try to follow one tutorial for apply TSNE on PCA (https://medium.com/@gabrieltseng/clustering-and-collaborative-filtering-visualizing-clusters-using-t-sne-f9718e7491e6)
 at this link

and i make this:

[image]

My question is: 
**I dont think is very good way to cluster. For you guys, this is significative cluster? Make it sense to do this with full matrix?**

i see example in the Iris dataset and the cluster will be create, because value of Iris have really similar value. 
In my case one user can be 5 on one component and -5(too far) on other...So for me this maybe don't make sense..right?

Just for clarification i wish add an screen of my matrix review:

[image]

I m really crazy with this..

Answer (score 0):

On data set such as the movielense data, clustering usually does not work as one would naively expect.

1. Not all users belong to clusters of "typical" interest
2. Many users will have multiple interests
3. Importance of variables varies
4. Missing values do not correspond to a 0 rating

That is why for *recommender systems* you use for example factor-based and itemset-based approaches.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I construct a matrix factorization to fill "missing value". In that way seems work because for user that like a "Star wars" suggest to see other similar movies. By the way i wish visualize in the plot this , so after i apply PCA and T-SNE, just because i think, that i had all metrics and i try to calculate distance